# Trouble with dynamic form values with PHP

Tags: php, forms, loops, foreach

I have a loop in a form for dynamically adding/removing items, however, only the last item is removed every time. I can add items just fine though.

I can't figure out why no matter which items I try to remove from both add_friends and register_tasks, ONLY the last item is removed. When I echo $_POST['task_name'] it's always the last item on the list, never the one I selected(unless of course I select the last item).

Here is the form

```
 <center><h2>Create Event</h2></center>
        <form method="post"> 
        <?
        $form = new common_functions();

        if($form->check_saved_forms($my_username, "event") == TRUE){
            $this->existing_forms(); //allow the user to select existing forms that they have created
       }

        ?>               
        <tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type="text" width="20%" name="event_title" value="<? echo $form_data[0]; ?>" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Details:</td><td><input type="text" width="20%" name="event_details" value="<?echo $form_data[1]; ?>" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Date:</td><td><input type="text" width="20%" name="event_date" id="event_date" value="<? echo $form_data[2]; ?>" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td> <input type="submit" name = "submit_event" id = "lOBut" value="Create Event" /></td></tr>  
        </table>

    <?
    //this is the section giving me trouble
    $form->add_friends($added_friends); 
    $form->register_tasks($tasks,$nums); 
    ?>
    </form>
```

Both add_friends and register_tasks dynamically add and remove friends/tasks by a textbox, and a list of the added items are shown. users can remove items, however, right now only the last item is removable and I can't figure out why.

Here is register (add_friend is the same, but labeled differently)

```
function register_tasks($tasks,$nums){
    <table>    
    <td><input type="textbox" size="50" name="register_description"/> </td></tr>
    <td><input type ="textBox" name="register_num" /> </td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="add_register_tasks" value="Add"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    <?
    if(count($tasks) > 0){
        ?>
        <table>
        <tr><td><b>Registration Item Description</b></td><td><b># Of Available Spots</b></td></tr><br>
        <?
        foreach (array_combine($tasks, $nums) as $task => $task_num){
            ?>
            <tr><td><? echo $task; ?></td><td><? echo $task_num; ?></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="remove_task" value="Remove"/></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="task_name" value="<? echo $task; ?>"/>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="task_num" value="<? echo $task_num; ?>"/></td></tr>

            <?
        }
        ?></table><?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the form tag inside the loop. Right now what happens is all the records are displayed in a single form and no matter what item you choose, it takes only the last value. Another alternate solution would be to use GET method and pass the number/name as query string.

Comment: Would I still need form tags if I were to use a GET method? Would any of the information entered in the text boxes have to be POSTED at some point so it's not lost if the user wants to remove a name from the list?

Comment: you can choose to use GET or POST whatever you wish. You can handle the requirements in both ways. If you do not want to show information in URL then use POST, otherwise GET is fine. When you use GET method, you don't need form tags at all